# Please set the JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: java

I'm trying to run jfoenix demo but i got this:
[image]
how can i fix it?

[image]

Comment: It looks like JAVA_HOME has a semicolon after it, so maybe set JAVA_HOME=(the directory in the error, without the ; at the end?) Semicolons are used in PATH variables so that Windows can see/try more than one directory, but you don't need them for variables that point to just one directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove this character ";". It should works. Good look.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/oqytgr

Comment: how i make this?

Comment: in my system variable does not have this;

Comment: That's what I seeing on your second image. You need to remove that character to make it works.

Comment: And also you should restart your computer after do it.

Comment: wtf but how do i do it?

Comment: You just need to edit that variable on your settings.

Comment: omg i delete and now no have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197770/discussion-between-nathaniel-and-joao-spirit).

Comment: it was just that I had to remove and add again